# Match column names to list of row names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A          B      C        D      E            F        G        H
1                 Q1     Q2      Q3     Q4        Asset 2      Q4
2   Asset 1       15     85      90     70        Asset 3      Q2
3   Asset 2       40     80      45     60        Asset 3      Q4
4   Asset 3       30     60      55     60        Asset 5      Q1                 
5   Asset 4       12     72      25     15
6   Asset 5       60     48      27     98
7
```

In `Cells A1:E6` I have different assets with their performance from quarter `Q1-Q4`. 
In `Column F` I currently list all assets that have a performance of `60`.

As you can see it can happen that an asset is listed multiple times in `Column F` since it can have the same performance mulitple times in `Cells A1:E6`. In this case `Asset 3` has a performance of `60` both in `Q2` and `Q4`.

Now, I want that in `Column G` the quarters are automatically matched to each asset. 
 Do you have any idea of a formula that could do this considering that an asset might be listed mulitple times?

Comment: The best way to to do this is probably with a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a formula, use this array formula

```
=INDEX($1:$1,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$E$6=$G$1)*($A$2:$A$6=H1),COLUMN($B$2:$E$6)),COUNTIF($H$1:H1,H1)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Much cleaner solution

Comment: Thanks again Scott.

Answer (score 0):

hard coded something things, and worked with the layout provided.

```
="Q"&AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(INDEX($B$2:$E$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1)/($A$2:$A$6=F1),1),0))/(INDEX($B$2:$E$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1)/($A$2:$A$6=F1),1),0)=60),COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1))-1
```

[image: POC]

This does kind of cheat as it is concatenating the column number and the letter Q.  For something that actually looks at your header and could be located anywhere the update formula could be:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(INDEX($B$2:$E$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$6=F1),1),0))/(INDEX($B$2:$E$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$6=F1),1),0)=60),COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1))-COLUMN($B$2)+1)
```